# Libgdx texture sizes, developing for bigger resolution than my laptop's

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently working on a libgdx game and before I give it final touches I wanted to actually hear something from experienced users, that has been bothering me for a few days already.
 If I want to support as many as possible devices, essentially I will be designing graphics for the biggest possible res ,which is then going to be scaled if needed, for smaller screens, right? How do I go about developing for a resolution that is even bigger than my laptop's(the 2015/16 gen phones). My laptop has a resolution of 1920x1080px and the S7 Samsung has 2k+ width.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you not trust that it will scale up correctly for some reason? I doubt you need to make assets for resolutions greater than 1080p. AAA console games don't even go above that. Unless you expect to have a lot of customers with tablets and your graphics are excellent.

Comment: Sure it will, but it will be distorted, what is evetually gonna look ugly and spoil the game...

Comment: It won't look distorted if you are using Viewports.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried with a 650 x 365.625 window, which I then compiled on an android device with the res of 2560x1440, it looked kinda stretched and distorted

Comment: I'm sure, if you're doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). You have to decide which strategy fits best your needs. For example a `FitViewport` always keeps the aspect ratio you define, which might lead to black bars on some devices.

Comment: I am using that already and thats's correct what you said for aspect ratios. But my question has nothing to do with the aspect ratio. My laptop has a resolution of 1920x1080px and the S7 Samsung has 2k+ width. That just does not fit on my screen

Answer (score 0):

When I personally develop with libgdx I place and size all objects relative to the screen width and height. This includes images, fonts, buttons, etc. This gives me a pretty consistent result across all devices because most devices today have a ratio 16:9 or something close to it. For developing an image larger than your screen size what's wrong with just using photoshop to create the image of the specified size?

Answer (score 0):

Better you choose the screen with as 1280 and screen height as 800 and also use the fill viewPort . So you will be able to render your game in almost all the screens without the issue of stretching.
Viewport is the method which provided by the libgdx to solve this multi screen compatible issue . here i will post some sample code which you can use for the reference.

public class myGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

```
public OrthographicCamera camera;
public Viewport viewPort;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont myScoreFont;
private Texture texture;

public myGAme() {

}

@Override
public void create() {
        myScoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.PATH_TO_MY_SCORE_FONT), true);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.PATH_TO_LEFT_BAR));

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.update();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Constants.APP_WIDTH, Constants.APP_HEIGHT);

   // Here is the viewport is setting up with the camera and the screen size

    viewPort = new FillViewport(1280, 800, camera);



}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
}



@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(myScorefont,"Score",0,0);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
// the game area will be resized as per the screen size of the device
    viewPort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
```

}